# Duplicate (Copy/Paste) sub-tree in Structure

Tags: structure, duplicate

Has anyone come across an addon or method to duplicate a sub-tree in the Structure addon? Have a client where we're using Structure to assemble training courses (Course > Topic > Content/Quiz) and we want to be able to 'duplicate' a Course and tweak it for different audiences where required.

Comment: I'd suggest rephrasing your question to be "how to..." vs. "have you seen..."?