# How to Duplicate a Structure Tree or subtree?

Tags: ee3, duplicate

EE3: I am wondering if anybody knows a way to duplicate an entire Structure Entry Tree including child entries. It has been asked before, without an answer [here](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/15514/duplicate-copy-paste-sub-tree-in-structure).

How could I achieve this?

*optional: If that doesn't work, how can I duplicate an entire channel?*

*There's a plugin called MXCloner which currently isn't EE3 ready (or can anybody tell me I'm wrong? But the description on devot-ee and author's site is not very clear if it can duplicate more than one entry at a time. No mention of channels.*